# Getting Astro Project to pick up source of multiple directories of Mark Down Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, astrojs

I wish to create a project that translates Mark Down files (MD) to html. I'm using Astro because of it's support of MD to HTML although I'm new to ASTRO or JSX style code. This project seems like a great starting point. However, the working version only has one sub-dir of Markdown files in directory 'src\content\newsletter'. When I attempt to add a second sub-directory with different MD files, I get an error similiar to the following:

```
> npm run build

 generating static routes 
▶ src/pages/index.astro
  └─ /index.html (+14ms)
▶ src/pages/docs/[slug].astro
 error   Expected "slug" to match "[^\/#\?]+?", but got "console-apps/autoclientcreation"
  File:
    C:\Dev2\Documentation4\content-collecttion-api-example-main\node_modules\path-to-regexp\dist\index.js:229:27
  Code:
    228 |                 if (validate && !matches[i].test(segment)) {
    > 229 |                     throw new TypeError("Expected \"".concat(token.name, "\" to match \"").concat(token.pattern, "\", but got \"").concat(segment, "\""));
          |                           ^
      230 |                 }
      231 |                 path += token.prefix + segment + token.suffix;
      232 |
```

**Starter Project**
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Ekwuno/content-collecttion-api-example

**My Project** with two directories of Mark Down Files.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [rest parameter](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#rest-parameters) (`[...path].astro`) to match files of any depth.

In this case `src/pages/docs/[...slug].astro` allows your file to match any route of any depth under `/docs/**`.